# Assuming no compiler optimization, how many times will this object be created?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Assuming there is no compiler optimization. How many times would OutputBuffer_s type object will be created?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct OutputBuffer_s {
    int encoded[10];
};

OutputBuffer_s func() {

    OutputBuffer_s s;

    return s;
}

int main() {
    OutputBuffer_s a = func();
}
```

Initially, I had assumed three times.

1) When func() is called, object `s` will be created on stack.

2) When func() goes out of scope, it will return copy of object `s` to main().

3) Copying of value to object `a` in main(), since value returned by func() would be a temporary.

I know that I'm wrong here, since I compiled with `-O0` in `g++` but I could see only one creation after overriding the constructors. I want to know where and why I am wrong.

Comment: 3) `a` is copy constructed or even move constructed, because `func()` returns an rvalue.

Comment: Why does that matter to you? Be aware of the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule). Even `g++` with `-O0` is doing *some* optimizations.

Comment: which version of C++ are you using?

Comment: [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) allowed before C++17, mandatory in some cases since C++17.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "as-if" could apply in this case - but it is not really relevant to copy-elision.  Copy-elision is specifically allowed even if the elided constructor or destructor have side-effects.

Comment: My understanding is that copy elision is a special case of the as-if rule.

Comment: @SumitDhingra: Posted an answer taking into account C++11 and C++17 as well.

Comment: @P.W C++11 version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have here [copy-elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

> Omits copy and move (since C++11) constructors, resulting in zero-copy pass-by-value semantics.

GCC can elide the constructors even with `-O0` option. This is what is happening here. If you want to specifically prevent elision, you can use the `-fno-elide-constructors` option.

If you use this option, there will be one constructor call and two move constructor calls for C++11.

See [demo here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/304ea3230f0e2e10)

If you use C++17, there is guaranteed copy-elision in some cases, and here even with the `-fno-elide-constructors` option, there will be one constructor call and just one move constructor call.

See [demo here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b730ceab25ece46)

Comment: With `c++17` it goes down to one constructor and one move.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll try to read more about it.

Answer (score 2):

C++17 has introduced Temporary materialization which I quote:

> A prvalue of any complete type T can be converted to an xvalue of the same type T. This conversion initializes a temporary object of type T from the prvalue by evaluating the prvalue with the temporary object as its result object, and produces an xvalue denoting the temporary object. If T is a class or array of class type, it must have an accessible and non-deleted destructor.

In that case the extra calls to the *contructor* will become a *move* operation. Prior to C++17, which copy elision was not mandatory, the compiler would **usually** copy elide. As far as I am aware, in your case, a compiler would copy elide anyway (try godbolt and check the produced assembly).

To fully answer, one call to the constructor and one move.